# How to find exact format of a date string?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, date-format, culture

I need to know exact date format that will perse the string `16-Aug-78 12:00:00 AM`. I have tried various string like "ss-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss". Is there any way for finding it to converting to any general format. I am using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string format is wrong. It has to match your string format **exactly**. You can use `dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt` format instead.

Here an example in [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/).

```
string s = "16-Aug-78 12:00:00 AM";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt",
                               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
date.Dump();
```

- [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Or, since `dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt` is a standart date and time format for [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can directly [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like;

```
string s = "16-Aug-78 12:00:00 AM";
var date = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
date.Dump();
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/sRMuxu)</kbd>.

> Is there any way for finding it to converting to any general format?

There is no way to get format of a string except you create your own formatting. Only you can know what is your string format exactly, computer can't.

For example; `01/02/2014` can be *1 February 2014* or *2 January 2014* depends on which custom format you can parse it.

Comment: Thank you. It helped me. But is it possible to try few formats with priority then try which format is application to get exact value. I have done it by nested try catch. Is there any better way.

I have noticed that my format is wrong.

Comment: @pcbabu You are welcome. `DateTime.TryParseExact` method [has an overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes format as a _string array_. That means you can provide multiple string format in your method. If your string matches one of your formats, this method return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong format string, you are using ss for day it should be dd. This article [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains what you need for custom format.

*Use*

```
"dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt"
```

*Instead of*

```
"ss-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss"
```

You can use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) to parse the string.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("16-Aug-78 12:00:00 AM", "dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as below

```
var dstring = "16-Aug-78 12:00:00 AM";
DateTime result;
var matchingCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).FirstOrDefault(ci => DateTime.TryParse(dstring, ci, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [DateTime.TryParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx):

```
string strDate = "16-Aug-78 12:00:00 AM";           
DateTime datDate;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(strDate , new string[] {"dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss tt" },
                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                       System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out datDate))
 {
   Console.WriteLine(datDate);
 }

 else
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Error in datetime format");
 }
```